# Best schema for Company with several Offices in Schema.org

Tags: schema.org

For example, a port services company has several offices around the world. What is the best schema to represent both company and offices?

Should I use `Organization` for both and relate the offices to the company through `parentOrganization`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think the [`parentOrganization`](http://schema.org/parentOrganization) (or for the other direction: [`subOrganization`](http://schema.org/subOrganization)) property should be used here.

Each office should probably be a [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), which allows you to provide opening hours (e.g., with [`openingHoursSpecification`](http://schema.org/openingHoursSpecification)); something which [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) doesn’t allow.